# Как можно обнулить элементы списка, расположенные между его минимальным и максимальным элементами?

Tags: python, list

Дан список натуральных чисел. Нужно обнулить элементы списка, расположенные между его минимальным и максимальным элементами. Нужно самое простое решение чтобы результат выглядел вот так:

```
[6, 8, 1, 5, 4, 10, 3] -> [6, 8, 1, 0, 0, 10, 3]
```

либо:

```
[6, 8, 10, 5, 4, 1, 3] -> [6, 8, 10, 0, 0, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Решайте большую задачу по частям - для начала найдите индексы минимума и максимума

Comment: Приведите Ваш код, пожалуйста, на каком этапе вычислений Вы зашли в тупик?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [6, 8, 1, 5, 4, 10, 3]

x, y = a.index(min(a)), a.index(max(a))
x, y = sorted((x, y)) 

a[x + 1:y] = [0] * (y - x)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Код мало того, что не для новичка, который циклы только учится писать (ведь автор вопроса именно такой?) и выглядит как издевательство, преподаватель такое не зачтет. Так он еще и не соответствует заданию, т.к. заточен, что `x < y`. `[6, 8, 10, 5, 4, 1, 3]` - этот список он оставит без изменений.

Comment: @mrEvgenX вы можете написать ответ через циклы и где вы все объясните. Я обязательно поставлю голос за